# System.net.mail attachment gets .xml file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail

I have to mail several files to an e-mail address. The files needs to have .tcx file extension. These are in fact xml files (Garmin bicycle logs).

Apparently when the receiver gets the email, the attachement is named xxxxx.tcx.xml. How can I force the mailer not to change the attachment file name?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;

namespace stravamailer
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\JurgenS\\Downloads\\allrides");

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();
                oMail.Body = "";
                oMail.From = new MailAddress("jurgen@ccccc.be","Jurgen Stillaert");
                oMail.Subject = "";
                oMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("jurgen@cccc.be"));
                Attachment att = new Attachment(files[i]);
                att.Name = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
                oMail.Attachments.Add(att);

                SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient("uit.telenet.be");
                oSmtp.Send(oMail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try sending it to another email address (totally different provider; like gmail or hotmail) to see if the attachment gets renamed also. I have a feeling it's because of the receiving mail server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Attachment class is used with the MailMessage class. All messages
>   include a Body, which contains the content of the message. In addition
>   to the body, you might want to send additional files. These are sent
>   as attachments and are represented as Attachment instances. To add an
>   attachment to a mail message, add it to the MailMessage.Attachments
>   collection.
>
> Attachment content can be a String, Stream, or file name. You can
>   specify the content in an attachment by using any of the Attachment
>   constructors.
>
> The MIME Content-Type header information for the attachment is
>   represented by the ContentType property. The Content-Type header
>   specifies the media type and subtype and any associated parameters.
>   Use ContentType to get the instance associated with an attachment.
>
> The MIME Content-Disposition header is represented by the
>   ContentDisposition property. The Content-Disposition header specifies
>   the presentation and file time stamps for an attachment. A
>   Content-Disposition header is sent only if the attachment is a file.
>   Use the ContentDisposition property to get the instance associated
>   with an attachment.
>
> The MIME Content-Transfer-Encoding header is represented by the
>   TransferEncoding property.

[Here is the source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx)

Your solution is in this MSDN link. you should try MIME Content-Type.

Comment: files[i] is a string: the file path.
There is nothing like new Attachement(filepath,filename). I do try to rename the file by setting the att.Name. I also tried to set this to "myride.tcx" and it keeps on adding .xml.

Comment: Thx, it was indeed contenttype: ContentType ct = new ContentType("application/vnd.garmin.tcx+xml")